# Estimating compound growth

Tags: finance, estimation

I have a compound interest function with the following parameters:

Value at time 0 = 13.8
Interest rate = 0.05
time interval = 10

I need to check quickly, (without a calculator, only pen and paper) which of the following options represents the minimum interest rate to represents at leat 50% of the first interest function.

Value at time 0 =3.3
time interval = 10
interest rate A = 0.05
interest rate B = 0.10
interest rate C = 0.15
interest rate D = 0.20

The growth is given by the formula:

```
 V_10 = V_0 x ( 1 + i)^10
```

Is there some quick mental algorithm to do these computations to estimate the right answer?

Comment: Any of them do, since [$(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) for $x>0$, so you need, if I read correct, $(1+x)^{10} \ge 1.5$, but the minimum rate given is $0.05$: $(1+0.05)^{10}>1+0.05\cdot 10=1.5$

Comment: Not really, you need to compared the 3 options with the first option which is 22.8 at period 10

Comment: $13.8\cdot 1.05^{10}\cdot 0.5$ must be $<3.3\cdot (1+x)^{10}$ and we check if $0.10,\,0.15,\,0.20$ fits for $x$, correct now? I do no know how to do this by hand...